# how to get content by element in ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I have a scene like this:

`<div *ngFor="let page of pages" #parentContent>
    <ion-content></ion-content>
<div>`

There are many ion-content in this, and I want to "scrollTop" at every ion-content.

I can get #parentContent by `@ViewChild('parentContent') parentContent: any;`

And also I can get it's children by `parentContent.children[index]`

But how can I get it's Content like `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content`

Because I want to do `content.scrollTo(x,y,duration)`,but `parentContent.children[index]` only has `scrollTo(options?: ScrollToOptions)` and it doesn't support many browser（I use it in chrome is feasible,but it's unfeasible in Android webView）
However `parentContent.children[index]` support scrollTop, but it hasn't smooth animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let page of pages">
    <ion-content #subcontent></ion-content>
<div>

@ViewChildren('subcontent') subcontent: QueryList<Content>;
```